# How to JOIN these 3 tables together in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

So I have 3 tables in total called companies_company c, companies_sharedtrainingunit cst and companies_trainingunit ct. The first JOIN I created joined c and cst on the same company id.

```
SELECT c.id as consuming_company_id, c.name as consuming_company_name, cst.id as channel_connection_id, cst.training_unit_id as channel_id
FROM companies_sharedtrainingunit cst
FULL JOIN companies_company c ON c.id = cst.company_id
ORDER BY company_id ASC
```

which yields a table with results like

| consuming_company_id | consuming_company_name | channel_connection_id | channel_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | company_1 | 2000 | 100 |

Now I want this joined table created above joined to the same info from table c and a new table ct ie

```
SELECT c.id as owned_company_id, c.name as owned_company_name, ct.id as channel_id, ct.name as channel_name, ct.description as channel_description
FROM companies_trainingunit ct
FULL JOIN companies_company c ON c.id = ct.company_id
ORDER BY c.id
```

| owned_company_id | owned_company_name | channel_id | channel_name | channel_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | company_2 | 100 | channel_100 | description_100 |

I have tried joining these two queries but no luck :(

I know they need to be joined on their channel ids

In the end I am looking for my table to looking something like:

| channel_connection_id | consuming_company_id | consuming_company_name | channel_id | channel_name | channel_description | owned_company_id | owned_company_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | company_1 | 100 | channel_100 | description_100 | 2 | company_2 |

Comment: If you have three tables, sample data from each would be helpful.  Also, you can set up a db<>fiddle of some sort.  Show the query you have "no luck" with.

Comment: The data you gave don't seem to match. Shouldn't `consuming_company_id` be the same as `owned_company_id`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry should've specified better, consuming_company_id and owned_company_id are different. They are connected companies via a channel which I am trying to show by this JOIN

Comment: What is the connecting element between the result rows you show?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the channel_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to join with `companies_company` twice. Also, an inner join is sufficient:

```
SELECT cst.id as channel_connection_id,
       c1.id as consuming_company_id,
       c1.name as consuming_company_name,
       cst.training_unit_id as channel_id,
       ct.name as channel_name,
       ct.description as channel_description,
       c2.id as owned_company_id,
       c2.name as owned_company_name,
FROM companies_sharedtrainingunit cst
   JOIN companies_company c1 ON c1.id = cst.company_id
   JOIN companies_trainingunit ct ON cst.training_unit_id = ct.id
   JOIN companies_company c2 ON c2.id = ct.company_id
ORDER BY cst.company_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a `left join` starting with `companies` to be sufficient to get the rows you want.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT c.id as consuming_company_id, c.name as consuming_company_name,
       cst.id as channel_connection_id, cst.training_unit_id as channel_id,
       ct.id as channel_id, ct.name as channel_name, ct.description as channel_description
FROM companies_company c LEFT JOIN
     companies_sharedtrainingunit cst
     ON c.id = cst.company_id LEFT JOIN
     companies_trainingunit ct
     ON c.id = ct.company_id     
ORDER BY c.company_id ASC;
```

Comment: I got this : ERROR: column reference "company_id" is ambiguous Position: 524

Comment: also It needs to have the owned_company_id and owned_company_name, which are different companies to the consuming ones

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to understand your data model. There are tables with "trainingunit" in their names, but there is no trainingunit ID. Instead there is a "channel_id" you want to join on. Why is that?

Then, you are using full outer joins to include companies without training units and training units without companies. Does that even make sense?

However, provided your queries are correct and you want to join them, just do so:

```
select *
from
(
  SELECT c.id as consuming_company_id, c.name as consuming_company_name, cst.id as channel_connection_id, cst.training_unit_id as channel_id
  FROM companies_sharedtrainingunit cst
  FULL JOIN companies_company c ON c.id = cst.company_id
) q1
(
  SELECT c.id as owned_company_id, c.name as owned_company_name, ct.id as channel_id, ct.name as channel_name, ct.description as channel_description
  FROM companies_trainingunit ct
  FULL JOIN companies_company c ON c.id = ct.company_id
) q2 using (channel_id)
order by channel_id;
```